# Mysql .net Connector 6.6.x DbMigration EF 4.3 cascade delete

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, mysql-connector

I have code first models with the latest 6.6.x beta driver working.
Dbmigrations seem to be working fine as wel.

However there seems to be a problem with cascade settings.
My models have cascade delete all over them, but the database that gets generated does not reflect these settings.

On the mysql website in the change log there is something mentioned about cascade delete nog generated correctly in the sql create script , but i do not know if this is also for dbmigrations.

Anyway it does not seem to work?
Anyone that seen the same behaviour?